# Predict_proba on a binary classification problem

Tags: classification, probability-calibration

I have a binary classification task on my hands, i have a bunch of people that i need to classify as being ones or zeros and then use ***predict_proba*** to estimate how confident my prediction was on the samples used for inference.
My understanding is that **predict_proba** for most classification algorithms isn't accurate and needs to be **calibrated**. Is there a common approach to get objectively accurate class probabilities ?
**Algorithms names** , **techniques** and some **code** if possible. Thanks!

**Note** : my classes are imbalanced 80/20.

Comment: please take a look at this answer https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/54993/52089

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sklearn` provides us with [two methods](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV.html#sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV) to calibrate a probabilistic classifier via their `CalibratedClassifierCV` class; one using Platt's scaling (sigmoid) and one using isotonic regression.

Another method is by using a [Venn-Abers predictor](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.0025), which is not implemented in `sklearn`, however you can find a custom implementation [here](https://github.com/ptocca/VennABERS).

As for imbalanced datasets, make sure to exploit the `class_weights` argument of an `sklearn` classifier, to increase the weight of under-represented classes.